# Salted hash generator

Tags: c#, hashcode

I've had a go at creating a small class in C# that can generated salted hashes from text. I would like to know how this could be improved (in terms of code style) and whether or not this code is secure enough that it could be used in a professional environment (it won't be).

**Hasher.cs**

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace HashAndSaltTest
{
    public static class Hasher
    {
        private static readonly int MaxSaltLength = 32;

        public static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(byte[] plainText)
        {
            HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] salt = GenerateSalt();
            byte[] saltedText = new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
                saltedText[i] = plainText[i];

            for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length; i++)
                saltedText[plainText.Length + i] = salt[i];

            return algorithm.ComputeHash(saltedText);
        }

        private static byte[] GenerateSalt()
        {
            byte[] salt = new byte[MaxSaltLength];

            using (RandomNumberGenerator random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
                random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);

            return salt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to use this code for? How do you intend to verify the hashed value?

Comment: If "plainttext" is ever going to be a password, this is not secure. SHA256 is not designed to handle passwords (use PBKDF2 or bCrypt instead). If you're not using it with passwords, I don't get the purpose of the salt. A bit more context of what kind of input is expected and what'll you use the hashes for is relevant when speaking about security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Because `HashAlgorithm` implements `IDisposable` you should enclose the usage of it in an `using` block as well.
- Omitting braces `{}` although they might be optional can lead to hidden and therfor hard to find bugs. I would like to encourage you to always use braces.
- Instead of using a `for` loop to copy `plainText` to `saltedText` and `salt` to `saltedText` you may take advantage of the `Array.CopyTo()` method.
- `Public` methods should validate passed parameters.
- Because you don't return the `salt` you can only generate a hash but you can't verify the hash.

Applying the mentioned points can lead to

```
public static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(byte[] plainText)
{
    if (plainText == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText"); }
    if (plainText.Length == 0) { throw new ArgumentException("Length may not be zero", "plainText"); }

    using (HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        byte[] salt = GenerateSalt();
        byte[] saltedText = new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];

        plainText.CopyTo(saltedText, 0);
        salt.CopyTo(saltedText, plainText.Length);

        return algorithm.ComputeHash(saltedText);
    }
}

private static byte[] GenerateSalt()
{
    using (RandomNumberGenerator random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[MaxSaltLength];
        random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just wondering, from a security standpoint, how safe is this method of generating salted hashes?

Comment: IMO its safe enough at least if the `plainText` isn't containing security relevant information. If `plainText` contains security relevant information you should override it inside this method.

Comment: @Heslacher, could you elaborate on `you should override it inside this method` a little, and/or show an example? I'm assuming`security relevant information` would be passwords and such.

Comment: I meant overwriting the passed array.